# SQL: Filter equal and not equal queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tried below queries, but none of them works - result was blank. I want to filter the equal and not equal in one query, using SQL Server 2012.

Query #1

```
Select * 
from MainDB 
where STATES = 'CA' 
  and FILECODE = 'WER' 
  and not SOURCE = 'Export'
```

Query #2

```
Select * 
from MainDB 
where STATES = 'CA' 
  and FILECODE = 'WER' 
  and SOURCE != 'Export'
```

Query #3

```
Select * 
from MainDB 
where STATES = 'CA' 
  and FILECODE = 'WER' 
  and SOURCE <> 'Export'
```

Comment: do you get an error message?

Comment: What can we do with "Not Working"??????  At least tell why is not not working, error message???  blank???  wrong result???

Comment: Result was blank @SqlACID

Comment: @RomartDubluis Do you have leading spaces?

Comment: I hope you are using default collation on your db. If not, that could be a case sensitivity issue.

Comment: Tried to use below query and it works but when i need to put another filter result was blank:
`Select * 
From MainDB 
where STATES = 'CA' 
  and SOURCE != 'Export'`

Comment: Thanks, It's already Fix i reinstall the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NOT IN`

```
Select * 
    from MainDB 
    where STATES = 'CA' 
      and FILECODE = 'WER' 
      and SOURCE NOT IN ('Export')
```

Comment: Also have blank result on this query.

Comment: @RomartDubluis - Can you please give some sample data

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a good practice to install SP's in time but also to follow a code syntax.. query 3 should be always Ok..
The only thing I would add is that a sequence of conditions is also playing a role sometimes.. it would be better to use a bigger limitations as a first condition so next will be looping a smaller data set..